# Sort dict in-place

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

How do you sort a dict in-place? It doesn't have a sort method like `list.sort`?

```
d = {3: 'three', 1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
tmp = dict(sorted(d.items()))
d.clear()
d.update(tmp)
```

Want result like this ^ but should be proper in-place i.e. without using up double memory. And other references to the same object should see the re-ordering!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to do that. Dicts are order-preserving now, but just preserving - they're not designed to support complex order manipulation operations.

The dict implementation change that lead to order-preserving dicts is fundamentally very limited in the kind of order manipulation it can support. The dict's hash table stores indices into a dense array of entries, and it is this array that maintains the dict's element order.

The dense array cannot be reordered arbitrarily without invalidating the hash table. Even removing an entry has to be implemented as leaving a dummy marker in its place, for collision resolution purposes, and that entry's spot cannot be reused without a full hash table rebuild.

Even if you were to try to perform some sort of inefficient, manual sort by removing and replacing entries, you would accumulate dummies and trigger a hash table rebuild, consuming the extra memory you didn't want to use. Here's a quick-and-dirty demo:

```
import os

os.system(f'grep VmPeak /proc/{os.getpid()}/status')

x = dict.fromkeys(range(2**16))

os.system(f'grep VmPeak /proc/{os.getpid()}/status')

for i in range(2**16):
    if i == 21845:
        os.system(f'grep VmPeak /proc/{os.getpid()}/status')
    k = next(iter(x))
    x[k] = x.pop(k)
    if i == 21845:
        os.system(f'grep VmPeak /proc/{os.getpid()}/status')

os.system(f'grep VmPeak /proc/{os.getpid()}/status')
```

Output:

```
VmPeak:    15092 kB
VmPeak:    20224 kB
VmPeak:    20224 kB
VmPeak:    24832 kB
VmPeak:    24832 kB
```

Instead of an actual sort (which would consume extra memory or cost a lot of extra time), we use an already-sorted dict and repeatedly extract the first key in the order and place it at the end of the order, matching the access pattern a remove-and-replace sort would perform to sort this dict. When we hit the threshold for a dict rebuild, peak memory usage immediately jumps due to the need to allocate a second copy of the dict's internal data structures.

Comment: Wasn't the order preservation actually a happy accident anyway

Comment: @SuperStew: Pretty much.

Comment: @SuperStew the change to `dict` was made for better efficiency, but as a side effect it also preserved insertion order.  It wasn't quite an accident, but it wasn't the reason for the change either.

Comment: well there is a way to do it because I can find the min key each time and delete it, inserting to end, and count how many insertions. eventually the dict will be sorted??

Comment: @COVFEFE-19: Even that isn't really "in-place", because you'll trigger a hash table rebuild and use the extra memory you didn't want to use anyway.

Comment: why does it trigger a rebuild? the dict shouldn't get any bigger this way, and not any new keys were added?

Comment: @COVFEFE-19: You fill up the dict's dense value array with dummy entries and it needs to clear those.

Comment: @SuperStew its same keys (just rearranging) so they should hash the same no?

Comment: if there is dense arrays underneath, it should be possible to interchange two key/val positions in the dense arrays.  how does list.sort work in-place if not the same way?

Comment: @COVFEFE-19 No. If you're really interested, go look into the detailed documentation and code.

Comment: @COVFEFE-19: Doing that would invalidate the hash table. Lists don't have a hash table to invalidate.

Comment: how does that completely invalidate the hash table and why the hash table is so fragile? you mean there is no way to repair the hash table when swapping position of two vals in the dense array storage?  some local change which preserves integrity and doesn't require O(n) space.

Comment: I accept the other answer because you don't provide sufficient evidence to back up these claims, I just have to take your word for it...

Comment: @COVFEFE-19: Instead, you picked an answer that doesn't fulfill your stated requirements, that explicitly calls out how it doesn't save you from extra memory usage? Odd choice.

Comment: Anyway, if you want more evidence, you can read the dict implementation, particularly https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Objects/dictobject.c, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Include/dictobject.h, and https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Include/cpython/dictobject.h

Comment: In there, you can see things like how `dict_pop` eventually delegates to `_PyDict_Pop_KnownHash`, which leaves a dummy marker with `dictkeys_set_index(mp->ma_keys, hashpos, DKIX_DUMMY);`, and you can see the complete absence of any functionality to swap entries or to place a new entry anywhere but at the end of the entry array.

Comment: With complete, unrestricted access to the dict's internal C-level data structures, you could theoretically compactify the entry array, sort it, and then wipe and rebuild the hash table, but the dict's public API doesn't expose anywhere near what you'd need for that, and you'd have to implement your own sort, because Python's built-in sort can only operate on a list. (That includes `sorted`, which builds a list internally.)

Comment: Well can you add memory benchmarks which show that sorting with pop/insert to end does actually cause double memory usage in practice anyway? That's what I meant by evidence, not just links to source code (it's too complex to understand without hours of study)

Comment: @COVFEFE-19: I've added a quick demo showing the extra memory consumption.

Comment: What is the significance of 21845? That's when a hash table rebuild triggered? I was not able to reproduce this result, I've tried this on a Linux box and VmPeak just stayed at 402796 kB the entire time (high water mark?). I tried it on a Windows box (WSL) and it was 0 kB the entire time. On a macOS box the `/proc` directory didn't exist.

Comment: @COVFEFE-19: 402796 sounds like you ran it in an environment where you'd already done work that consumed a lot of memory. Try putting the code in a standalone file and running `python thatfile.py`. As for 21845, that's when the rebuild happens.

Comment: @COVFEFE-19 `tracemalloc` might be better, [shows me](https://tio.run/##fY7NasMwEITveoq9WQqpISmUUkieorcQgmqv7cXWD6sNtZ/elZWW9lRdBDPfzGxcZAj@@TXyupKLgQWEbYPOTlNowCYQp9QMJ2ipkbrj4EZckmbre9TH3e7wYoxS4uoklkUbFdGOGc9Kj3IrZe3NoQu8aHM5XJXqAgMBefhb8qYgvy3pcRZNgqznXL2p82W8ZmOuY4h6fGjbzPHfnY2i7hs8l/8x8hPP6WL@ikxedFU88g2jTdiChGpfwD1UH4tggs8B8/H4RD4hC/k@A9ntpnsaTu98R7OuXw) a peak increase from 388 bytes to 5243036 bytes when re-inserting 21845.

Answer (score 3):

Technically you can sort the keys and then `pop` reinsert the values. This way other references to the same object will see the change as well. It won't save you from additional memory usage though.

```
for key in sorted(d):
    d[key] = d.pop(key)
```

Depending on the load factor of the dict this can trigger quite a number of hash table rebuilds and hence slow down the computation as can be seen from the following example:

```
In [1]: def inplace(d): 
   ...:     for key in sorted(d): 
   ...:         d[key] = d.pop(key) 
   ...:                                                                                       

In [2]: def create_new(d): 
   ...:     return dict(sorted(d.items())) 
   ...:                                                                                       

In [3]: import math                                                                           

In [4]: limit = (2/3) * 2**20                                                                

In [5]: load_factor_low = {i: i for i in range(math.ceil(limit) + 1)}                        

In [6]: load_factor_high = {i: i for i in range(math.floor(limit) - 1)}                      

In [7]: %timeit create_new(load_factor_low)                                                         
116 ms ± 1.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit inplace(load_factor_low)                                                     
104 ms ± 2.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [9]: %timeit create_new(load_factor_high)                                                        
89.8 ms ± 1.45 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit inplace(load_factor_high)                                                    
128 ms ± 1.52 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: yes, it works! but the sorted(d) still make an full array of keys, doesn't it?

Comment: Runtime and memory, pick one to sacrifice.

Comment: @COVFEFE-19 It does, so it won't buy you much.

Comment: This ends up using the extra memory the question wanted to avoid anyway, because it triggers a hash table rebuild when dummy entries pile up too high. It only **looks** in-place.

Comment: In fact, peak memory usage is likely higher this way, because you have the `sorted` list and both the old and new versions of the dict's internal data structures in memory at the same time while the rebuild is happening. With `dict(sorted(d.items()))`, that doesn't happen.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica does `sorted` retain the memory? Say if a generator is used instead, would that avoid some memory headspace if it's critical? My guess is the difference won't be much anyhow.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Actually, rethinking it again, I don't think this version has higher peak memory usage. `d = dict(sorted(d.items()))` holds two versions of the dict and the sorted list in place, so it will use about 3x the memory of `d`. Similarly the pop-reinsert version guarantees that the size of the dict `d` will never grow beyond its current size, so during the hash table rebuild there exist also only two versions of the original dict, i.e. it has similar memory usage. However it might trigger more than one hash table rebuild.

Comment: `d = dict(sorted(d.items()))` holds two versions of the dict at once, but you can drop the first one after the sort: `sorted_items = sorted(d.items()); del d; d = dict(sorted_items)`. You could also just clear and repopulate `d`: `sorted_items = sorted(d.items()); d.clear(); d.update(sorted_items)`.

Comment: That said, I didn't initially notice that your code does `sorted(d)` instead of `sorted(d.items())`. Those tuples are pretty big, and avoiding them helps.

Comment: I also forgot to explicitly drop the first version of `d` when I commented earlier. That's my mistake.

Comment: @a_guest  Could you put memory benchmarks instead? These are more relevant to the Q that timeit results..